# Action on $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, quotient-group

Let $2^n - 1 = rt$. Сonsider map $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_r \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_r$ such that $\phi(a) = 2a$. The question is how many orbits this action has?
Clearly we can see that if $a \equiv a2^m \text{ mod } r$ so orbit's order is $ m-1 = |\mathrm{Orb}(a)| \leq n $ because $r \mid 2^n - 1$. And there is only one orbit that has order 1, the others has order $2^k$. Nothing more I can say.

Comment: If $a\equiv 2^ma$ then the orbit size is some divisor of $m.$ it is $m$ only if $m$ is the least such $m.$ The orbit size is never $m-1,$ unless $m=2,$ since $m-1\mid m$ implies $m=2.$

Comment: So every orbit has a size equal to a divisor of $n.$ But we don't know if an orbit can even have size $n$ unless we have more information than $2^n-1=rt.$

Comment: In particular, the order of $2$ in $\mathbb Z_r$ is a divisor of $\phi(r).$ We can do even better, if $r=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ then the order of $2$ is a divisor of $\operatorname{lcm}(\phi(p_1)^{a_1},\dots,\phi(p_k^{a_k}))$ and a divisor of $n.$

Comment: That order of $2$ modulo $r$ will give the size of orbits when $\gcd(a,r)=1,$ but that won't work for $\gcd(a,r)\neq 1.$

Comment: For any $d\mid r$ the set of $k\in \{0,1,\dots,r-1\}$ such that $\gcd(k,r)=d$ is $\phi(r/d),$ and they are divides into $o_{r/d}(2)$ orbits.

So, replacing $d$ with $r/d,$ the sum you want is: 

$$\sum_{d\mid r}\frac{\phi(d)}{o_d(2)}$$ where $o_d(2)$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $d.$

Comment: So for $r$ prime, you get: $1+\frac{r-1}{o_r(2)}.$